# Lifehacker: Best Question and Answer tool

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

[Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5727190/best-online-question-and-answer-tool) is asking for nominations for the "Best Question and Answer" tool.

I humbly suggest that it is the Stack Exchange family of sites. If you agree, you may want to nominate it yourself.

***Update***: [Stack Exchange came in a distant second to the mighty Goog](http://lifehacker.com/5730944/best-question-and-answer-tool-google).

Comment: Pharyngulate that sucka!

Comment: @random - need to add that to my list of pause operations.  "Pharyngulating suckers" should fit right after "Embiggening prototypes" and before "Reticulating Splines"

Comment: @random Sounds painful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Jeff already tweeted about this.](http://twitter.com/#!/codinghorror/status/23267504516235264)

> vote #stackexchange for your favorite online Q&A tool! http://goo.gl/BNlAA

Comment: Oh. Well then. This can be deleted if it's not necessary.

Comment: @AlEv, I'm not sure that's necessary.  I think it can stay.

Comment: They seem to be removing comments though: Mine (between @BPhillips' and @GuardianOfChaos' entries) just disappeared. Plus, you'd expect there to be *many* more entries if Jeff tweeted about this 12 hours ago. Am I overlooking something? Anyway, I'll try again in case it was my fault

Comment: Ah: "To prevent tampering with the results, votes from first-time commenters may not be counted" Fair enough, I guess.

Comment: @Pekka, ah.  That makes sense.